# How to find proper integrating factor to solve non-separable differential equation $(2x^2+\frac{x}{y^2})dx+(\frac{x^3}{y}-\frac{x^2}{y^3})dy=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve the following differential equation:

> \begin{equation}
> \left(2x^2 + \frac{x}{y^ 2}\right)dx + \left(\frac{x^3}{y}-\frac{x^2}{y^3}\right)dy = 0
> \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{2x^2y^ 2 + x}{y^ 2}\right)dx + \left(\frac{x^3y^2-x^2}{y^3}\right)dy = 0
\end{equation}

I first tried to check if its separable by rearranging and simplifying terms

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{y(2xy^2 +1)}{x(xy^2-1)}\right) dx = dy 
\end{equation}

But it did not work so unless I made a mistake its a non-separable differential equation. I learned that to solve these I need to use integrating factors. Could someone please explain me how to know select the proper integrating factor to use? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiplying factor $x^ay^b$ in equation and finding $a$ and $b$ the integrating factor is
$$\mu=\color{blue}{\dfrac{y}{x}}$$

**Alternative method:** Drop a $x$ of equation, then
$$
\left(2x + \frac{1}{y^ 2}\right)dx + \left(\frac{x^2}{y}-\frac{x}{y^3}\right)dy = 0
$$
and rearranging gives
$$2x\ dx  + \frac{x^2}{y}\ dy+ \frac{y dx-x dy}{y^3}=0$$
$$2xy\ dx  + x^2\ dy+ y\dfrac{1}{y}d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=0$$
$$d(x^2y)+d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=0$$
$$x^2y+\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=C$$

Comment: thanks for help. I think that I understand the alternative method following your steps. But I dont understand how the first method work.  I would multiply the both sides of equation by $x^a y^b$ and then solve for a and b?

Comment: find parameters $a$ and $b$ such that _the terms in parenthesis have equal powers_ or another way is _when the equation be exact_.

Comment: By the way, I was also wondering how can I check whether the equation is exact or not?

Comment: With common notation $M_y=N_x$.

Comment: But I thought that is a condition for equation being separable. Is separable and exact the same thing?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: $(xe^{xy}-1)dy+(2+ye^{xy})dx=0$ is exact, is it separable ?

Comment: oh okay its definitely not separable but how come its exact? Following your notation $M_y = N_x$ the way how I understand it is that on one side I must have some function $M$ which is function of only y and on other side I need to have some function $N$ that is function of only x, or am I missing something?

Comment: I meant $Mdx+Ndy=0$ is exact when $M_y=N_x$.

Comment: Here $M_y=N_x=e^{xy}(1+xy)$

Comment: oh okay I think I got it now thanks for all the help and patience

Comment: You are welcome :)